# hidden scrollable div, should work in all browsers

Tags: html, css, angular

In my angular application, I want a hidden scrollable div.

Below link for those who don't know how it how it look likes...

http://jsfiddle.net/5GCsJ/4713/

I have fixed-header and fixed-navigation in my application. Rest of all the content should come inside a scrollable div having scroll bar hidden.

This is how my project looks like

[image]

I want that red marked area inside scrollable div.

This is my main layout html file.

```
<sa-header></sa-header>


<sa-navigation></sa-navigation>


<div id="main" role="main">

<sa-ribbon></sa-ribbon>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>

</div>
```

In this, I want the `<router-outlet>` should come inside the scrollable div.

I have tried this example code http://jsfiddle.net/5GCsJ/4713/ but this didn't work for me.

Then I tried this approach below but Its only working in Chrome, not in IE or FireFox.

```
  ::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
  }
```

Want something that should work in all browsers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-while-still-being-able-to-scroll

Comment: see supporting here:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do it:

```
/* internet explorer and edge */
section {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;

}

/* chrome, safari and opera */
section::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```